# problems on changing opacity with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, opacity

I have this code which brings focus to the Nav-bar element by fading the opacity on `mouseover`

here it is:

```
$("#Nav-bar").mouseover(function(){
    $(".content").animate({opacity: 0.3,}, 350 );
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(".content").animate({opacity: 1.0,}, 350 );
});
```

The problem here is the page is constantly going in and out of the effect when browsing along the element. such as when I hover a link, the page fades out then in again. How do I stop this?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WQY7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function to release previous animations.

```
 $("#Nav-bar").mouseover(function () {
     $(".content").stop(true).animate({
         opacity: 0.3,
     }, 350);
 }).mouseout(function () {
     $(".content").stop(true).animate({
         opacity: 1.0,
     }, 350);
 });
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WQY7/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Its working perfectly, and thanks for the link to the function. How did i miss this?